# Load multiple files in corresponding variable in R

Tags: r, loops, batch-processing

Is there a way of saying something like:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  ga${i} <- read.table(file="ene.${i}.dat",header=T, sep = ",")
}
```

in R.

I tried using many other constructs, but none suited the requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract file names first.

```
ga <- lapply(list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.dat"), read.csv)
```

or with loop:

```
lf <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.dat")
ga <- structure(vector("list", length(lf)),
                names = gsub("\\.dat", "", lf))
for (i in seq_along(ga))
    ga[i] <- read.csv(lf[i])
```

To assign data to the separate variables:

```
lf <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.dat")
fn <- gsub("\\.dat", "", lf)
for (i in seq_along(lf))
    assign(fn[i], read.csv(lf[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty list and then a paste function to do something like this:

```
ga <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  ga[[i]] <- read.table(file = paste('ene.', i, '.dat', sep = ''), header = TRUE, sep = ',')
}
```

Then, you will have a list of data frames. You can index as ga[[1]], ga[[2]] etc. to access them.

Comment: but since ``sep`` is ``,`` why not just use ``read.csv(paste0('ene.',i,'.dat'),header=T)``

Comment: Yes, you can. I was showing a generic version with options to help understand different elements. Your code is more compact.